# Unexpected error -50 after Mac wakes up from sleep

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, sleep-wake

2 months ago I had [strange problems with my Macbook Pro 13", 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270419/macbook-pro-sata-cable-controller-problem) which I luckily fixed by replacing the SATA cable. However, since last week I have another really strange issue. Every time after my Mac wakes up from 'Sleep', I get the following error:

> The operation can't be completed because an unexpected error occurred
>   (error code -50).

I removed my Samsung SSD 850 Evo and put the standard Mac HDD in my Macbook and everything seems to work fine, except it is slow as hell (but no error -50 after waking up from sleep).

My best guess was that the SSD is damaged, since the 'First aid' feature of Disk Utility notices that something is wrong. However, this only happens when the SSD is build in my Macbook. I did the same by plugging it in externally on another Mac, and no errors noticed by 'First aid'.

I also did the Apple Hardware Test to see if there are any other hardware failures, but all the tests were fine.

Yesterday, I got a kernel panic, but solved it by clearing the NVRAM.

I forgot to mention, often, when booting from the SSD (internally), the Mac crashes halfway through the boot process. I was able to reproduce the issue on my other, working Mac: Halfway-through the progressbar on boot up, the Mac unexpectedly shutdown.

What could be the problem? What should I do now?

Comment: What file system format is the SSD in?

Comment: It is `OS X Extended`.